# underscore _.range() not work at AngularJS ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, underscore.js

If I want only 20 iteration, how can I repeat my block?
It isnt work:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in _.range(20)"></div>
```

UnderscoreJS included in the page

Answer (score 18):

If you want to use undersore's functions in your template you will have to expose it on a scope. If you want to have it available in all templates one way of doing so would be:

```
var app = angular.module('angularjs-starter', []);

app.run(function($rootScope){
  $rootScope._ = _;
});
```

Then you could use it in a template as you've tried:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in _.range(20)">{{item}}</div>
```

Here is a working plunk: http://plnkr.co/edit/1Va4EikvRyFiQvhb2HYV?p=preview

**While the above works it shouldn't be used**. Model should be initialized in a controller. Otherwise AngularJS will execute `_range` on each $digest cycle to generate a new array.

Comment: As Pawel mentioned, this solution is uneasy. the problem with this solution is ng-repeat won't be able to optimize at all.  Each time angular dirty-checks `_.range(20)` it will get a new array back - and then ng-repeat, since it has a new array object, will create twenty **new** elements each time.  If ng-repeat finds the same array instead, it could save the elements.  You should do what Pawel said and do `$scope.range20 = _.range20` or something - and only regenerate it when you need a new range.